# Question about fixed-navbar + text-align right CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

just starting out on my code journey and am hoping you can shed some light here. I just can't quite figure out how to adjust my code to reflect what I'm trying to do. I've tried to use float:right but then it seems to tamper with my ability to modify margins afterwards.

I've tried to adjust padding/margin/ text-align and can't seem to get my navbar text to the position that I want. What I want is to align it right, 
 and then offset it from the top where it is, and then to create space between the words for presentation. I'd like to keep it as a fixed navbar with the logo and text present during scrolling, at all times.

Here's a link to jsfiddle for an example, see below for my topnav CSS code.

https://jsfiddle.net/gbr403/t1u7q3wL/

```
.topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%;
    height: 63px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  }
```

Comment: i didn't quite understand how exactly you want your navbar to look. As far as i understand, you want your navbar to be fixed at top of the page, logo to be displayed at left corner and text at right corner?

Comment: Ok so, I want the left side to contain the logo which should stay on the navbar as the user scrolls.  Right side, I want the navbar links to be present. I actually figured it out... lol. I'll try to be more clear next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to align items in navbar. See example below

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar,
.navbar--links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.navbar--logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar--links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 18px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/258174/pexels-photo-258174.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="navbar--logo"/>
  <div class="navbar--links">
    <a href="#Mission">Mission</a>
    <a href="#Featured-Tea">Featured Tea</a>
    <a href="#Locations">Locations</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css flex. The Flexible Box Layout Module, makes it easier to design flexible responsive layout structure without using float or positioning.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%;
    height: 63px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:center;
}
.topnav a {
    font-size: large;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#img1 {
    
}
#logoid{
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;    
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
  <div class="image1">
    <img id="img1" src="">
  </div>
  <div class="topnav">
    <div class="navlogo">
      <img id="logoid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#Mission">Mission</a>
      <a href="#Featured-Tea">Featured Tea</a>
      <a href="#Locations">Locations</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>1111<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>2222
</body>
```